# Create a URL for each chat

Tags: php

I have an online chat. I want every user to create their own chat that other users can join. But the problem lies in the chat url. How to make sure that when you create a chat, a new chat and url appears?

My SQL:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `messages` (
  `mes_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `user_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `mes_body` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `chattime` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`mes_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=13 ;


INSERT INTO `messages` (`mes_id`, `user_id`, `mes_body`, `chattime`) VALUES
(2, 8, 'go', 1370846012),
(3, 8, 'not go', 1370846029),
(4, 8, 'go', 1339742113),
(5, 8, 'hi dream', 1370241527),
(6, 3, 'ji', 1370846786),
(7, 3, 'nice job', 1370846856),
(8, 8, 'hi threr', 1370847094),
(9, 3, 'hi', 1370851056),
(10, 3, 'hi', 1370851838),
(11, 1, 'I have to go there ', 1370852157),
(12, 3, 'I have to make my ajax style more attractive and beautiful so be carefull about your style', 1370852536);


CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `user` (
  `user_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `username` varchar(250) NOT NULL,
  `password` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `online_status` int(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`user_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=9 ;


INSERT INTO `user` (`user_id`, `username`, `password`, `online_status`) VALUES
(1, 'jim', '123', 0),
(2, 'jack', '456', 0),
(3, 'dreams', '218837', 1),
(4, 'Tuhin', '789', 0),
(5, 'sadi', '456', 0),
(6, 'sadi', '456', 0),
(7, 'sadi', '456', 0),
(8, 'admin', '2013', 1);


CREATE TABLE `all_chats` (
  `chat_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `title_id` varchar(225) NOT NULL,
  `mes_id` int(225) NOT NULL,
  `user_id` int(11) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;


ALTER TABLE `all_chats`
  ADD PRIMARY KEY (`chat_id`,`user_id`);


ALTER TABLE `all_chats`
  MODIFY `chat_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT;COMMIT;
```

Here is my code:

```html
<?php
error_reporting ('E_ALL_E^NOTICE');
session_start();
require_once 'class/dbconnect.php';
require_once 'class/database.php';
require_once 'class/login.php';

$database=new database($db);
if(isset($_POST['action'])){
 $login->check_login($_POST['username'],$_POST['password']);
 
 }
 
$login->isLogin();

?>
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<link href="cs/chat_style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<link href="cs/settings_chat.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<title></title>

</head>

<body>
<?php
if (isset($_POST['adChat'])) { 
 $chat=$this->db->query("INSERT INTO `all_chats`(`title`, `chat_id`, `user_id`, `mes_id`)
  VALUES (:chat_id,:title_id,:mes_id,:user_id)");
$chat->bindParam(":chat_id",$user_id,PDO::PARAM_INT);
$chat->bindParam(":title_id",$title,PDO::PARAM_STR);
$chat->bindParam(":mes_id",$message,PDO::PARAM_STR);
$chat->bindParam(":user_id",$user_id,PDO::PARAM_INT);
$insertMessage->chat(); 
}
?>
<div class="chat-settings">Настройки чата</div>
<div class="settings">
<form name="form" action="" method="post">
<input type="text" name="title">
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Изменить название группы">
</form>
</div>
<input type="button" name="adChat" value="Создать чат" onclick="location.href='index.php?chat_id=<?php $chat_id ?>'">
<?php 
if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{
 extract($_POST);
 $titleChange=$db->query("INSERT INTO `chat`(`title`) VALUES ('$title')");
} ?>
<div class="chat_container">
<div class="name"><?php echo $title; ?></div>
<div class="chat_box">
</div>
<div id="write_msg">
<textarea id="message" placeholder="Write Your Messge TO your Frientds"></textarea>
</div>
<a href="index.php?logout=11">Logout</a>
<div id="whoisonline">
<h3>Online now</h3>
<ul>

</ul>
</div>

</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't really want to go in detail how to create it. But I'll try to explain. So if user creates a chat you create the chat record in database with unique id. Then you need to be able to list the available chats with urls that has the id as the property like `/chat.php?chatId=<actual_chat_id>` then you would be able to create a chat.php file that would be able to use `$_GET['chatId']` and go get the chat and display it from the database on the page depending on the the chat.